# Wicket : FileUploadPage doesnt refresh the filepath

Tags: file-upload, wicket

again, i got a problem with wicket. Im trying to upload data with my Class "FileUploadPanel", which is implemented on another Page "Class A":

**Class A**

```
...
/* uploadfields for Picture and Video */
ArrayList<String> picExt = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> videoExt = new ArrayList<String>();
picExt.add("jpg");
videoExt.add("mp4");
final FileUploadPanel picUpload = new FileUploadPanel("picUpload", "C:\\", picExt);
final FileUploadPanel videoUpload = new FileUploadPanel("videoUpload", "C:\\", videoExt);

final Form form = new Form("form"){
      protected void onSubmit() {
      ...
      // Save the path of Video and Picture into Database
      table.setVideo(videoUpload.getFilepath());
      table.setPicture(picUpload.getFilepath());
      ...
}
...
```

**Class FileUploadPanel**

```
public class FileUploadPanel extends Panel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2059476447949908649L;
private FileUploadField fileUpload;
private String UPLOAD_FOLDER = "C:\\";
private String filepath = "";
private List<String> fileExtensions;

/**
 * Constructor of this Class
 * @param id the wicket-id
 * @param uploadFolder the folder, in which the File will be uploaded 
 * @param fileExtensions List of Strings
 */
public FileUploadPanel(String id, String uploadFolder, List<String> fileExtensions) {
    super(id);
    this.UPLOAD_FOLDER = uploadFolder;
    this.fileExtensions = fileExtensions;
    add(fileUpload = new FileUploadField("fileUpload"));
}

@Override
public void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag){
    // If no file is selected on startup
    if(fileUpload.getFileUpload() == null){
        return;
    }
    final FileUpload uploadedFile = fileUpload.getFileUpload();
    if (uploadedFile != null) {

        // write to a new file, 
        File newFile = new File(UPLOAD_FOLDER
            + uploadedFile.getClientFileName());
        filepath = UPLOAD_FOLDER + uploadedFile.getClientFileName();

        // if file in upload-folder already exists -> delete it
        if (newFile.exists()) {
            newFile.delete();
        }

        try {
            newFile.createNewFile();
            uploadedFile.writeTo(newFile);

            info("saved file: " + uploadedFile.getClientFileName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error");
        }
     }
}

public String getFilepath() {
    return filepath;
}
```

}

Well, if i use the submit-Button on my "Class A", the Pic and Video get saved on C:\, which is quite good so far. I thought i finally get along with wicket, but i cheered too soon...

Problem: The correct path is not saved in the Database, which is handled in the Form of "Class A"
I really dont get it, because the onComponentTag(...) of my FileUploadPanel must be executed when using the submit-button. Thats because i added some validations like "picture must be a JPG or wont be saved" in onComponentTag(...) - and that worked. So im sure, the onComponentTag(...) is executed when the Submit-Button of the Form is used, which also means the filepath should be up-to-date.

What is it im doin wrong this time?

Thank in Advance!

Greeting
V1nc3nt

Answer (score 0):

You are using

> File newFile = new File(UPLOAD_FOLDER +
>   uploadedFile.getClientFileName());

this code to create a new File.

**Instead** of it you can try this one :

> File file  = new File(UPLOAD_FOLDER ,
>   uploadedFile.getClientFileName());

And then get the **absolute path** and **save** it:

> newFile.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: Thanks four your Answer. I tried that, but its not helping.
What i just found out, is, that if i upload a second file, it has the path of the first one.
Could it be, that the onComponentTag(...) of Class FileUploadPanel is executed AFTER the submit-Button of the Form in Class A is pressed?
What i did then, is overwriting the onComponentTag(..) of the **FileUploadField in Class FileUploadPanel's Constructor**. This is updated once the file is selected, so i thought it might be helpful to call:
    FileUploadPanel.this.onComponentTag(tag);
in it. But it didnt work either...

Comment: are you using wicket 1.4 or wikcet >= 1.5?

Comment: The difference in FileUploadField from 1.4.x to 1.5.x is that now it supports <input type="file" multiple/> (HTML5 standards) and it works with List<FileUpload> instead of just FileUpload. See this [docs link](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/upload/FileUploadField.html#getFileUploads())

Comment: public java.util.List<FileUpload> getFileUploads()
Returns:
a list of all uploaded files.

Comment: Oh i see. But for fileUpload.getFileUpload(); the doc says:
"Returns:
the first uploaded file if HTML5 <input type="file" multiple /> is used and the browser supports multiple, otherwise returns the single uploaded file."
That should be fine in this case, isnt it?

Comment: Well i found a "solution" to the problem, which i dun really like, but it works. Im just calling this in the Form of Class A before getting the source-path:
`picUpload.onComponentTag(null);
 videoUpload.onComponentTag(null);`
I hope there's a better way to do that =/